# nextjs i18n: move position of language code in url

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

We are working on a nextjs app with i18n. Now nextjs adds the language code in url automatically like `/{language-code}/subroute/my-page`. But we need it to be like `/subroute/{language-code}/my-page`. Is it possible through some configuration?

I checked `basePath` at https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath, but it adds a prefix to ALL pages in the app. We just need some pages.

Also there is a so-called `middleware` to add custom routing rules: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware. Is it possible to use it to need our needs?

Comment: It's possible to use either middleware or [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to map paths like `/subroute/:locale/my-page` to a destination like `/:locale/subroute/my-page`.

Comment: In case of rewrites Next Link will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @juliomalves, we have implemented the desired behaviors through [next.js rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites).

And @Aleksey Makas is right, for Next Link, we will need to do special treatments to move locale in the URL.